# No se actualiza la imagen en PHP

Tags: php

Tengo una aplicación en la que puedo subir fotos de perfil de usuario; el script funciona perfecto, el problema se genera cuando voy cambio de foto y la actualizo por otra sigue apareciendo la anterior, aun cuando la que tenia ya se ha borrado del directorio.

**Nota:** al cabo de un tiempo ya aparece la foto que he actualizado.

Comment: Supongo que es porque se esta almacenando en la cache del navegador, por eso cuesta que se actualice. tienes que agregar algo asi: `header('Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate');`
`header('Pragma: no-cache');`

Comment: voy a intentar amigo, la verdad no se que es y llevo mucho tiempo, el codigo parece que esta bien, pero en la vista no se muestra la imagen nueva

Comment: Por si acaso actualiza la página con Ctrl+F5 para que no use cache al recargar. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es la cache, a la url agrégale al final una variable con un numero aletorio
esto ahora que siempre que vuelva a cargar el script .
Ejemplo:

```html
<script src='http://www.pepepe.com/asdasd/index.js?update=<?php echo rand(); ?>'></script>
```

Comment: gracias, veo que esta es la soluciion mas obvia, y efectiva, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Si haces Control + Shift + R verás la imagen refrescada.

Los navegadores cachean las imágenes en base a una ruta, si quieres que la imagen cambie cada vez, debes cambiarle el nombre.

profile_01.jpg
profile_02.jpg

(El nombre de la imagen que se guarda en el servidor, no la que tu subes)

P.D: La respuesta es ambigua porque la pregunta también lo es :(

Comment: muchas gracias saludos, lo que pasa es que el nombre que le asigno a la imagen  es el id de cada usuario si el usuario, id 500 = 500.jpg, etc

Comment: Tendrás que cambiarlo a 500_0.jpg 500_1.jpg etc o si no cuando llames a <img src="500.jpg?ver=<?php echo time(); ?>" />